# Elastic search Nest index query always returning false

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

```
 var local = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(local, null);
            var elastic = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var res = elastic.CreateIndex(ci => ci
                               .Index("my_first_index_final2")
                               .AddMapping<BlogPost>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()));

            Console.WriteLine(res.RequestInformation.Success);

            var blogPost = new BlogPost
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Title = "First blog post",
                Body = "This is very long blog post!"
            };

            var firstId = blogPost.Id;

            var result = elastic.Index(blogPost, p => p
               .Index("my_first_index_final2")
               .Id(blogPost.Id.ToString())
               .Refresh());

            Console.WriteLine(result.RequestInformation.Success);
```

Blogpost class:

```
[ElasticType(IdProperty = "Id", Name = "blog_post")]
public class BlogPost
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "_id", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "title", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "body", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id: '{0}', Title: '{1}', Body: '{2}'", Id, Title, Body);
    }
}
```

This is my code. Everytime it returns:
true
false

Meaning, it creates index but unable to insert document into the index. I don't understand the reason.

Also, I have to rename my index name everytime i run this demo console application as i think we cannot insert index with same name. how can i avoid doing this?

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.devbridge.com/articles/getting-started-with-elastic-using-net-nest-library-part-two/

Any other resource for learning nest and elastic search, please feel free to suggest.

Comment: This issue might be caused by `refresh`, remove the `"Refresh()"` and try it again and let us know if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are using Elasticsearch 2.x. Your code won't break in Elasticsearch 1.x. The problem is, you are trying to add a field `_id` inside a document. It being one of the metadata fields, Elasticsearch 2.x prohibits you from indexing it inside the document. To make your code work, simply change the name of the `Id` field from `_id` to something different, say, `id`.

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Any suggestions on avoiding renaming the index everytime i am running console application? It would be great if you can suggest some other good tutorials to learn nest with elasticsearch basics.

Comment: Glad to help. Why don't you delete the index if it exists and then create the index? You can do all of this in code. You can get started with Nest at http://nest.azurewebsites.net/. Also this issue was pretty easy to debug. Had you seen the Elasticsearch logs, you would've known the root cause.